# Is masturbating with someone online zina?

Tags: zina, masturbation

Recently I went on a chat site and I met a girl. We chatted privately, aroused each other and then we masturbated together (she aroused me and I her). We then both climaxed and haven't spoken again. Is this zina?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but it is different form of zina than intercourse. It is zina of a lesser degree which does not trigger any hadd punishment. That does not mean it is not a sin. It is certainly a sinful act but of a lesser degree then unlawful intercourse. The following hadith is about this type of zina:

> It was narrated from Abu Hurayrah that the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “Allaah has decreed for every son of Adam his share of zina, which he will inevitably commit. **The zina of the eyes is looking**, the zina of the tongue is speaking, one may wish and desire, and the private parts confirm that or deny it.”
>
> Narrated by al-Bukhaari, 5889; Muslim, 2657.

Comment: can you please answer this zina related question: https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/43796/18985