# Can a muslim woman marry someone else if she had committed zina in a former illegal relationship?

Tags: halal-haram, fiqh, zina

I'm asking this question on behalf of a sister in Islam.

She was in an illegitimate relationship in which she committed zina and is now highly regretful.

What she wants to know is can she still marry someone else? Is there any ruling regarding this?

Please let me know.

This is not a duplicate question as this question asks about marriage with another man and not the same with whom he has committed zina.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it permissible to marry someone with whom you have had premarital sex?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/41494/is-it-permissible-to-marry-someone-with-whom-you-have-had-premarital-sex)

Comment: @G.Bach how can you mark it as duplicate? Please read the question and details carefully.

Comment: She made Tawbah ( regretted it , stopped doing it , and decided not to do it again )  , Then she can get married . She will not tell her husband anything about her past .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I be honest about premarital sex with a future husband?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/28467/should-i-be-honest-about-premarital-sex-with-a-future-husband) and [Can I still marry my cousin who may have had premarital intercourse with my other cousin?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/39767/20218)

Answer (score -1):

**Quran 24:3**

> الزَّانِي لَا يَنْكِحُ إِلَّا زَانِيَةً أَوْ مُشْرِكَةً وَالزَّانِيَةُ لَا يَنْكِحُهَا إِلَّا زَانٍ أَوْ مُشْرِكٌ ۚ وَحُرِّمَ ذَٰلِكَ عَلَى الْمُؤْمِنِينَ

**Pickthall translation**

> The adulterer shall not marry save an adulteress or an idolatress, and the adulteress none shall marry save an adulterer or an idolater. All that is forbidden unto believers

**Relevant Hadith**

> Abu Dawood (2051) narrated from ‘Amr ibn Shu’ayb, from his father, from his grandfather, that Marthad ibn Abi Marthad al-Ghanawi used to smuggle prisoners from Makkah. There was in Makkah **a prostitute** called ‘Anaaq and she had been his friend. He said: I came to the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) and said: O Messenger of Allaah, should I marry ‘Anaaq? He remained silent and did not answer me. Then the words “and the adulteress –fornicatress, none marries her except an adulterer — fornicater or a Mushrik” were revealed. He called me and recited them to me, and said: **Do not marry her**. *Classed as saheeh by al-Albaani in Saheeh Abi Dawood.*

It is forbidden to marry a **Zani/Zaniyah**. If you are fluent in Arabic, you can discern the grammatical difference between **a Zani vs. One who has committed Zina.** Zani/Zaniyah are individuals who are **actively fornicating (Prostitutes, Individuals in the dating scene, etc).** Allah is directly referencing Zani/Zaniyah - the ones currently being operative in the sin.

Therefore, unless the sister repents (search on how to make proper repentance/Tawbah) - she can only marry adulterers and/or polytheists. Indeed, the best solution to such a dilemma is repentance/Tawbah.

And Allah knows best.

Comment: *"she can only marry adulterers and/or polytheists"* ... Marrying polytheists is forbidden ([2:221](https://quran.com/2/221)).

Comment: @Uma Isn't that for chaste Muslims and those who have repented? Or are you saying that said verse abrogated verse 24:3? 24:3 clearly states that a Zani can marry idolaters (polytheists).